# Kinect - bitmap file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Does anybody know how I can save a greyscale image from the Kinect as a bitmap file? (python code)

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50374/kinect---bitmap-file/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be a somewhat roundabout approach, and something faster could be possible, but you could first get the openni driver from your Kinect, which is the openni_launch and openni_camera packages, then use rosbag to capture the data from the /camera/rgb/image_mono topic, which is the greyscale image. I don't know whether rosbag would save the captured data in the format you want so you will have to check on that. You can learn how to go about doing that in further detail with these links [www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/BagRecordingPlayback) and [www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch).

---

Originally posted by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) with karma: 93 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on 2012-12-13**:
I tried this tutorial, its works all till point 2.3, but when I will checking the conects of my bag with rosbag info kinect.bag I get this error message: ERROR reading kinect.bag: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'kinect.bag'

**Comment by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) on 2012-12-15**:
You probably don't have a file called 'kinect.bag'. It probably has a longer filename based on the time you captured the data. Make sure that you use the right filename in the command, and if you have issues with a corrupted rosbag file, use `rosbag reindex kinect.bag`.